# "реплика" - значение

Tags: семантика

Тоже из "актуального".

*Подросток размахивал пистолетом, который оказался **репликой** полуавтоматического оружия*

Раньше говорили, что в руках у погибшего чернокожего парня была игрушка. 
А "реплика" - это вроде как вполне себе работоспособная копия (обычно даже серийная, но другого производителя или под другим названием). 
Я прав?

(+)
*Подробности самого события меня здесь и сейчас не интересуют, думаю, уточнение скоро последует из прямых источников.*

Answer (score 1):

Да, если "реплика" – перевод слова "replication", то это "копия", "репродукция".

Меня больше забавляет слово "подросток". 18-летний парень – подросток?! Или это у нас так переводят "тинейджера"?

Comment: Это, видимо, разные случаи. Тому было 12 лет. 
А вообще-то подросток - один из возможных переводов тинэйджера.  

Только это не у нас. Это - "у них". Я пищу для размышлений вылавливаю в основном на "Евроньюс".

Comment: Переводить надо не слова, а смысл. 18-летний "тинажор" по-русски это "подросток", "юноша", "молодой человек".

Answer (score 0):

Если бы речь шла о "другом производителе" настоящего оружия, для содержания краткого репортажа такая подробность не имела бы значения (просто назвали бы марку оружия). Обычно в прессе в таких случаях говорят "муляж, имитирующий то-то".
По смыслу здесь модель ("игрушка" для коллекционеров), подробно имитирующая конкретную марку оружия ("модель" - один из возможных вариантов значения слова 'replica'). Фирмы-производители предлагают, большей частью, модели исторических марок огнестрельного и холодного оружия или оружия вымышленных видов, напр. из фильмов. Пример такой фирмы:
http://www.battleorders.co.uk/guns.html
Из описания одной из моделей "вальтера" видно, что, несмотря на имитацию некоторых движений, в ней не предусмотрено, напр., вынимание и наполнение магазина.

Comment: Так каков ответ-то? "Реплика" - это что? Пусть даже вне данного контекста?   
Рассуждать, что имеет значения для переводчика синхрониста - да еще на основании соображений явно далеких от его хлеба насущного - это как-нибудь потом...

Comment: Переводить им надо было "муляж такой-то винтовки (или пистолета)"; "репликой" называют разве что копии скульптур.

Comment: Так это в предположении, что это действительно был муляж...
Но в сочетании с упоминанием полуавтоматического оружия... Какой смысл в таком уточнении, если это муляж? Вот если это действительно рабочая, не игрушечная, копия, то вся фраза становится понятной и логичной. А история приобретает совершенно другой смысл.      
Впрочем, я сказал, сама история не интересует. Не сегодня - завтра уточнят, что там было на самом деле.     
Сейчас только значение слово "реплика". 
Значит я прав, что в таком виде фраза говорит о том, что парень баловался совсем не игрушечным пистолетиком.

Comment: Смысл уточнения в том, как это оружие воспринимают со стороны, например, служащие банка. Кому угрожали, тот описал, что видел.

Comment: Смысл уточнения в том, как это оружие воспринимают со стороны, например, служащие банка. Кому угрожали, тот описал, что видел.

Answer (score -1):

Уважаемый автор, Вы подняли не проблему значения "русского" слова [реплика]. А проблему отвратительного перевода, которая вытекает из общей проблемы помойного положения русского языка, в котором сейчас позволительно использовать любые иностранные слова, выдавая их за русские. Это как раз задача переводчика (это я как профессионал заявляю) перевести на РУССКИЙ язык смысл именно того, ЧТО было в руках у парня. А именно: копия пистолета, игрушка-пистолет и т.д. А переводчик вместо этого перевалил эту работу на слушателя/зрителя, теперь тот должен копаться в словарях, в энциклопедиях и справочниках, получать дополнительную информацию об этом событии, чтобы понять, ЧТО же было на самом деле в руках у парня, т.к. это ключевой момент всей ситуации. В языке-оригинале слово "реплика" (это просто как пример) может иметь 20 значений и покрывать и как "игрушку", так и "действующую копию". Поэтому, если переводчик по точному значению и по контексту не понимает, что это означает - "муляж" или "боевую копию", то должен был перевести общими понятиями, например "предмет, похожий на пистолет". А дальше, как Вы правильно отметили, поступила бы уточняющая информация. Вместо этого переводчик, расписываясь в своём бессилии, тупо озвучивает или пишет кириллицей "реплика" или "прайсы", или "шорт-лист", или "колл-центр" (хотя его даже не утруждаются писать по-русски, а пишут вообще латиницей call-центр, что особенно карикатурно: полслова по-русски, полслова - по-английски, кстати, это даже в нарушение закона о русском языке. Потому что писать "колл-центр" глупо - это там, где колы раздают? А "калл-центр" - вообще комично.) Или давайте с другой стороны подойдем. Вы переводите с русского на иностранный. И затрудняетесь, так как в языке-мишени нет точной параллели. И вы, как сейчас принято в нашу сторону, переписываете русское слово латиницей. Или вязью, или иероглифами и т.д. Скажите, милые люди, это кто-то пропустит? Да не вжисть!!! 1. На экзамене это "2" 2. На работе - не пропустит редактор. 3. А если проскочит, то осмеют носители языка и признают за вами невладение их родным языком. Кто не верит - попробуйте, особенно на экзамене! :) Забыл английское слово - вставляй русское с инговым окончанием. А мы посмотрим. Но ведь это сейчас легко проходит в нашу сторону. Сейчас ЛЮБОЕ иностранное слово (а английское - сам Бог велел) можно, и даже круто, вставлять в русскую речь, иногда обрусив его окончанием, суффиксом или приставкой, или переписать его кириллицей. При этом без малейшего намека на попытку перевести его на "лапотный" русский, истолковать, пояснить и т.п.. В сотый раз повторю, что этого позорища нет НИГДЕ в мире, кроме папуасов, пигмеев, попугаев и мартышек.

Comment: Я бы все-таки не советовал вам заполошничать. Видите ли, если вам (переводчику-профессионалу, как сами себя назвали) угодно ходить в мокроступах — никто этого запретить не может. Но вот читать вас вряд ли будут, разве только чтоб посмеяться.

Язык отражает жизнь. И "импортные" слова в языке появились не сами по себе и не по злому умыслу какой-то "мировой закулисы", которая только и мечтает, как бы испоганить великий русский язык. И не надо воображать себя "борцом" и "спасителем", это ребячество. Направьте свою бьющую через край энергию в мирное русло.

Comment: Смеётесь только вы, невежды, которые из иностранных языков выучили только один - русский. В других языках жизнь тоже самая современная, ваш любимый пример "компьютер": у французов, у арабов, у испанцев, у китайцев, у венгров, у армян, у ирландцев, у исландцев, у латышей, у норвежцев, у персов, у румын, у сербов, у словаков, у словенцев, у турок, у хорватов, у чехов, у шведов, у эстонцев, даже в африкаанс, да почти у всех остальных - их собственные слова. Таким, как вы - с отсутствующим логическим аппаратом, это донести НЕВОЗМОЖНО!!!

Comment: 2) Переводчиком не я сам себя назвал, а дипломы ещё советского образца. Мокроступы - прекрасное русское слово, сами сапоги от этого хуже не станут. Кстати, дореволюционная Россия была одна из лидеров по производству обуви. А брезговать русскими словами - удел духовных уродцев, культурных компрадоров. И "не сами по себе" и одновременно "не по злому умыслу" - посетите школьные курсы формальной логики и здравого смысла. И последнее - советуйте своей бабушке.

Comment: 3) В своём ответе я четко показал, что наши расеянские заимствования - это дикость, с точки зрения других языков и если это делать в противоположную сторону. ПО СУЩЕСТВУ моего ответа вы не в состоянии НИЧЕГО возразить! Только подтявкивать. Кстати, у меня много сторонников. По опросам ВЦИОМа 75% россиян ВОЗМУЩЕНЫ нынешней ситуацией с заимствованиями. Это же говорят почти все преподаватели русского языка вне Москвы и Питера. Скоро ваша антирусская "дедовщина" закончится. Какое же у вас огромное и бездонное сердце! Сколько туда вмещается ненависти! От неё в итоге сам и захлебнёшься...